# Unable to select value in a list from selenium python script

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have been trying to automate few action on a web based tool using selenium with python as scripting language.

So in this page, I have a field called status, here is the HTML code for this.

```
<div style="padding-left:105px" id="x-form-el-BugFieldsEditor_Status-desc" class="x-form-element x-form-el-BugFieldsEditor_Status-desc" role="presentation">
   <div class=" x-form-field-wrap  x-component " role="combobox" id="BugFieldsEditor_Status-desc" style="width: 230px;">
      <input type="text" class=" x-form-field x-form-text x-triggerfield-noedit" id="BugFieldsEditor_Status-desc-input" name="Status-desc" tabindex="1" readonly="" autocomplete="off" aria-owns="x-auto-462" aria-selected="" style="width: 205px;" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
      <img class="x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-arrow" src="https://someurl/clear.gif" id="x-auto-463">
   </div>
</div>
```

it actually appears as a compo box drop down list on the page. I am able to locate this element through find element by ID and able to simulate click event which brings up the list of option it contains. the HTML code of this is this.

```
<div role="presentation" id="x-auto-881" class="x-combo-list x-ignore x-component x-border " style="border-width: 1px; z-index: 1060; visibility: visible; height: 273px; width: 228px; left: 277px; top: 75px;">
   <div tabindex="0" hidefocus="true" id="x-auto-462" class=" x-view x-combo-list-inner x-component  x-unselectable " style="overflow-x: hidden; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; height: 273px; width: 228px;" unselectable="on">
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">A-Assigned</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">C-Closed</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">D-Duplicate</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">F-Forwarded</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">H-Held</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">I-Info_req</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">J-Junked</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">M-More</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">O-Opened</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item  x-view-highlightrow x-combo-selected" role="listitem">P-Postponed</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">R-Resolved</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item " role="listitem">U-Unreproducible</div>
      <div class="x-combo-list-item" role="listitem">W-Wait</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now the issue, on simulating click, though the list of option is displayed but I am not able to locate this element and select any option.

Can someone please help.

Comment: it wasn;t appearing for some reason. updated it and you should be able to see the same now.

Comment: did you tried with sendkeys?

Comment: that can be done only if the order and total number of option in this list are fixed. however that's not the case here. Number of option will be dynamic so I am looking at identifying them on run time based on linked text if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with an xpath selector like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="A-Assigned"]')
```

You may need to make the selector more specific depending on the rest of your HTML.